# When I follow vulkan-tutorial example code, validation layer doesn't work

Tags: vulkan, validation-layers

It's my first time to learnin vulkan. I try to follow https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers, but it doesn't work in using validation layer. Copy and paste this code(https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/02_validation_layers.cpp), but it throw this runtime error.

```
validation layers requested, but not available!
```

System PATH for vulkan(VK_SDK_PATH, VULKAN_SDK, and Path) set correctly. Could anyone give me some helps for me?

p.s. I tested [checkValidationLayerSupport() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS2dr.png) to know what `layerCount` value is. It was revealed `1`. Is it right?

**Environment**

OS: window(64-bits)

Vulkan SDK: 1.3.216.0(LunarG SDK)

GPU: GeForce GTX TITAN X (Discrete GPU) with Vulkan 1.2.142

Answer (score 1):

Try "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"